How to disable closing or minimizing X window
I want to disable closing or minimizing one of my windows (or to be more accurate, to remove the minimize and close buttons from the window). I was trying to change the _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS property of a window and remove all allowed actions using xprop. For instance, here are the initial allowed actions of a window:
$ xprop -id 0xa80000d WM_NAME _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS
WM_NAME(STRING) = "xterm"
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK

Trying to remove all allowed actions seems to be reflected correctly in xprop output:
$ xprop -id 0xa80000d -format _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS 32a -set _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS ""
$ xprop -id 0xa80000d WM_NAME _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS        
WM_NAME(STRING) = "xterm"
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = 

But nothing changed. Moreover, after I minimize the other window, I see the allowed actions return to the list:
$ xprop -id 0xa80000d WM_NAME _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS
WM_NAME(STRING) = "xterm"
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK

I tried it both on Xfce and KDE, on SLES15 and Ubuntu 20.04.
